# I think my cats have tapeworms. I gave them the first dose of meds. I got over the counter

Tags: cats, diseases, medicines

My cats have tapeworms i think. I gave them the first dose of meds today but nothing happened. What should i expect??

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE :) Please can you give more information about the treatment? Which company, which kind and which amount it was? How many cats do you speak about?

Comment: Welcome to Pets, answer needs more details, needs the name of the medicine being used, please include all the relevant details thanks.

Comment: i am allmost afraid of asking you this but what do you expect to happen?